# boost::variant of const and non-const

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I want to create `template< typename F > using T = boost::variant< F, F const >;` type to store read-only and read-write accessible values into the same `std::vector< T >`. But I've got the following programming problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main()
{
    using F = double;
    using CV = boost::variant< F const, F >;
    F const c = 0.0;
    CV C(c);
    F v = 0.0;
    CV V(v);
    std::cout << C.which() << ' ' << V.which() << std::endl; 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output: `1 1`.
How can I store the `const` version of the value of type `F`?

Comment: first of all you'd better to understand __why__... then look for solution. I'm digging a little into guts of `boost::variant` and discover that to initialize that different variants correct initializer called (i.e. `const` and non-`const`), but it returns invalid index for `const` parameter. `index` is a part of initializer type, which is obviously have some bug (or maybe feature)... so you'd better to dig into `boost::detail::variant::make_initializer_node` guts for answer (it is around line 111 of boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp)

Comment: @zaufi I will try. But it is seems too hard to understand.

Comment: reading (and understanding) code written by others is a **very** helpful skill anyway... use your chance to develop it! :))

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution, but something usefull:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main()
{
    using F = double;
    using CV = boost::variant< std::reference_wrapper< F const >, std::reference_wrapper< F > >;
    F const c = 0.0;
    CV C(std::ref(c));
    F v = 0.0;
    CV V(std::ref(v));
    std::cout << C.which() << ' ' << V.which() << std::endl; 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This requires an additional space to store the data if any. In some cases, it may be more appropriate than one in the original formulation of the question.